# GnuTLS recv error (-12): A TLS fatal alert has been received

Tags: web-crawler, pycurl, gnutls

I was doing some web crawling using pycurl on multiple servers and saw in the logs that there were some items that returned GnuTLS error as captioned. I manually checked the input parameters and they turned out fine when I ran my script locally.

My initial thought was that I might have gotten blocked by the site for hitting it several times but then when I researched this error, I saw where no one mentioned about being blocked.

I do not know what this error is and my only solution at this point is to implement something like an exponential wait to retry when it occurs. However, if anyone could offer some knowledge on this particular error, I would be very grateful for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the GnuTLS recv error is just an error based on network activities due site maintenance, upgrades, site being down, etc. Therefore, the solution around this is to provide a retry mechanism to try accessing the site. The retry mechanism could look something like an exponential backoff where it increases its wait time and try accessing the site again.